# Bubble charts with pie charts as bubble

Tags: excel, pie-chart

I wanted to create a bubble chart which means a scatter plot with a separate variable indicating diameter of bubble. Is there any way to use bubble then as pie chart? I would really like to do this in MS Excel but I just don't know whether it is possible.

---

I have another problem with the code proposed earlier in the post. Now that the first problem appears to be solved there is a problem in the line

`Set rngRow = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names(“PieChartValues”).RefersTo)`

and I tried to replace PieChartValues with the range  from the first row to the last in which the pie charts values ( the values from which the pie chart is generated) - like "A1:G12" and all the data are in that range. The tab in the sheet I am working in is called "B" without quotes should I write

`Set rngRow = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names(“B”).RefersTo)`

---

i tried to implement the code of a link proposed earlier in VBA this is

```
Sub PieMarkers()

Dim chtMarker As Chart
Dim chtMain As Chart
Dim intPoint As Integer
Dim rngRow As Range
Dim lngPointIndex As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set chtMarker = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(“chtMarker”).Chart
Set chtMain = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(“chtMain”).Chart

Set chtMain = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(“chtMain”).Chart
Set rngRow = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names(“PieChartValues”).RefersTo)

For Each rngRow In Range(“PieChartValues”).Rows

chtMarker.SeriesCollection(1).Values = rngRow
chtMarker.Parent.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
lngPointIndex = lngPointIndex + 1
chtMain.SeriesCollection(1).Points(lngPointIndex).Paste

Next

lngPointIndex = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

when I execute the code I get an error  pointing to the line
Set chtMarker = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(“chtMarker”).Chart

does anybody have an idea why? I have an object a pie chart named exactly chtMarker so the object should be there

Comment: Note you can do it in R with `floating.pie()` from the `plotrix` package

Comment: This capability is native to some GIS software, such as [ArcMap](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-desktop/features).

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it's not possible in Excel without an add-on or, perhaps, <s>extensive</s> programming. I would also urge you to consider other representations because pie charts are generally hard to read and scatterplots are already quite dense without adding a third dimension. Furthermore, a big problem with things like bubbles is that area grows faster than diameter so that visually a bubble with twice the diameter of another one will appear much bigger.

Specifically small multiples or scatterplot matrices could be useful, varying color along a continuous dimension could also allow you to represent a third quantitative variable.

Comment: Simple pie charts can actually work well on maps to show how proportions of quantities change with location. The quadratic scaling is no serious objection: by making the bubble diameter proportional to the square root of the size variable, the bubble areas will then be directly proportional to the size variable.

Comment: But then the diameter is not related to the quantity of interest and that's usually the way it is. Either way, it's difficult to know what to make of such displays. In practice, I still think it's a serious objection even if it might be more of a psychological/expectation issue.

Comment: One rarely perceives the *diameter* of a bubble directly; that's not how vision works. What is perceived is the *amount* of color in each slice, which is proportional to area. This is especially the case when looking at multiple pie charts. It's not in the least difficult to know what to make of such displays: produce one and look at it! If you're still unsure, you could test against a small human population to see how well and quickly people are interpreting the plot.

Comment: Regarding pie charts, I have seen some decent examples with two or three categories but even then, it's still not easy to read, compare specific categories and the like. One reason to consider them for maps is that common alternatives (say lines) would not be available in this case but does that mean they work *well*? I am still unconvinced.

Comment: Well, I often encounter such displays and what I learned is that I need to double-check if the scaling is reasonable (which it usually isn't). That's the problem I am trying to raise.

Comment: Although it might sound like we are arguing about something, I think we generally agree. My main point is that although multiples of pie charts rarely work *well,* sometimes they appear to be among the *best* options for certain kinds of data presentation, especially if some care is taken in their construction (as we discussed with the diameter *vs* area issue).

Answer (score 1):

Everything is possible in excel, but it can be long and painfull.

Unless... someone has already adressed the problem and gave the solution on internet.

Results for bubble charts pie charts Excel in google:

http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Create-Bubble-Pie-Chart-t781848.html
http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/pie-data-mark.htm
http://alesandrab.wordpress.com/2013/02/19/create-a-bubble-pie-chart-or-world-map-pie-chart-using-vba-and-excel-charts/

edit: I agree on the points evoked by the precedent answer;
If the chart is too complex to build you can always change the way you plot your data. It is an esay way to go. Sometimes you HAVE TO change the way you plot your data. (Yes the difficulty to build a chart is sometimes linked to its readability). Pie charts are not very good, mainly because you cannot compare them visually, specially if they are not the same size. It is a problem here because plotting multiple pie charts to compare them seems to be your goal.

Comment: OK, I stand corrected, programming it manually looks really quite easy if you are comfortable writing VBA.

Comment: Pie charts on scatterplots actually work pretty well, at least if they are simple (no more than 3-4 sections in each pie), because *en masse* they are visually interpreted as graduations of color across the plot, enabling almost instant apprehension of interactions (even nonlinear ones) between proportions (3-4 variables) and location (another 2 variables). There are few (if any) other effective techniques to discern such interactions for proportions.